# Firestore v9 Add subcollection on a document

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create subcollection on collection comments and on id that is random and unique to each post id on front end , this below code allowed me to do but nowhere enough it currently makes the structure as

/comments/380498/380498/0PDacNW1K70gAPBDWaXk

what i want is /comments/380498/0PDacNW1K70gAPBDWaXk

[image]

code for my firestore is given:

```
const details = { name, comment, mail, id };

  const dbRef =collection(db, "comments", id.toString(),id.toString());

  
  addDoc(dbRef, details)
    .then(() => {
      res.end("comment done");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.end("Internal server error try again later");
    });
```

Comment: @HirenF answer is correct. You may be interested by this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-define-the-collectionreference-of-a-subcollection-in-javascript-sdk-v9-c0ffb0459695) which shows different manners to define a (sub)`CollectionReference`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding for the sub collection seems to be wrong.

`comments/1234` is a document, hence you have to define a subcollection name under it.
`comments/1234/replies/` this can be your subcollection.

As for your code,

Below shall work.

```js
const details = { name, comment, mail, id };

  const collectionRef =collection(db, `comments/${id}/replies`);

  
  addDoc(collectionRef, details)
    .then(() => {
      res.end("comment done");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.end("Internal server error try again later");
    });
```

Comment: yeah i understood thanks for teaching me man, seeing it kinda diffrently my mind sucks haha thanks again

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Comment: yeah well i cant ask logical answers to chatgpt in the end programmers gotta be helpful to each other